# MediaExtractor, MediaMetadataRetriever with Raw/Asset File

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediametadataretriever

I try to read a video file inside either raw/assets folder, I have tried the following approaches but none of them works. I am testing on API 16. Each approach, I try with and without mp4 extension. I really appreciate that somebody can help me with it

All approaches will not crash, `MediaMetadataRetriever` can set data source, but cannot get width, height and screenshot. `VideoExtractor` always return

```
06-04 16:44:10.519: E/FileSource(8695): Failed to open file FILE_PATH. (No such file or directory)
06-04 16:44:10.519: E/DecodeActivity(8695): Can't find video info!
```

**Approach 1:android.resource**

```
String filePath = "android.resource://" + this.activity.getPackageName() + "/raw/green_backhand_slice";
videoExtractor.setDataSource(activity.getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(filePath), null);
metaRetriever.setDataSource(act.getApplication(), Uri.parse(filePath));
```

**Approach 2: android_asset**

```
this.filePath = "file:///android_asset/green_backhand_slice";
videoExtractor.setDataSource(activity.getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(this.filePath), null);
metaRetriever.setDataSource(act.getApplication(), Uri.parse(filePath));
```

**Approach 3: asset file descriptor**

```
AssetFileDescriptor assetFD = null;
try {
    assetFD = getAssets().openFd("green_backhand_slice.mp4");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

metaRetriever.setDataSource(assetFD.getFileDescriptor());
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here are some ways to do it:

1.raw:

```
final AssetFileDescriptor afd=getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.t);
mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
```

2.raw as uri:

```
final String uriPath="android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/t";
final Uri uri=Uri.parse(uriPath);
mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(getApplication(),uri);
```

3.assets:

```
final AssetFileDescriptor afd=getAssets().openFd("t.mp4");
mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
```

---

EDIT: another, in case you want to use the raw as a uri but got it without the name:

```
val uri= Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + resources.getResourceEntryName(R.raw.t))
```

Comment: Nice. I had problems with the Assets approach when providing ,afd.getStartOffset() and afd.getLength(). Adding them solved the issue.

Comment: @j7nn7k I don't understand, but I'm happy that this helped you.

Comment: I used `setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor())` which didnt work. `setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength())` worked